# Observe property in an extended class

Tags: dart, extends, observable, polymer

i am trying to bind values and observe from an extended class in dart, but somehow it is not working.

```dart
class Item extends ObservableBase {
  @observable String subject;

  Item(this.subject);
}

class TopItem extends Item {  
  TopItem(String subject):super(subject);
}
```

Using this binding not working:

```dart
topItem = new TopItem("subject");
<input type="text" value="{{topItem.subject}}"/>
```

If I use Item it is working fine.
What am I doing wrong here?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.

The question was answered by John Messerly on the Web UI mailing list (see https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web-ui/WRLhW8fIm_E/FGdtvvnADT4J).

You can read about the bug at:

https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/pkg/observe/lib/src/observable.dart#L117

Once the bug is fixed, I'll update the answer here.

Comment: @daftspaniel thank you for checking this with dart team. Credit should be yours, but this is the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your example working by changing the HTML to:

```dart
<template id="tmplsubject" bind>
Subject : <input type="text" value="{{subject}}"/>
</template>
```

With the model being defined as:

```dart
query('#tmplsubject').model = new TopItem("Dart");
```

This was using Dart SDK r27268.

Comment: I thought it was working, but if I add to the template another instance of it: `<p>{{subject}}</p>` it is first showing "Dart", but when i am amending it the p is not changing...